# Is it safe to move Linux partition (ext3) without breaking the Linux and its bootloader

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, grub, bootloader

This is my situation.
[image]

2. Windows 10
3. Ubuntu 14
4. Ubuntu's swap
5. unallocated space
6. partition which i don't need anymore

After i delete the last partition i would like to use the free space and distribute it between Windows and Ubuntu.

Windows utilities cannot move partitions, but some 3rd party programs (for example EaseUS) can. However i'm unsure, if i can safely move the Linux partition without breaking it somehow and without breaking the grub bootloader, which let's me select between Windows and Ubuntu at startup.

What method would you recommend?